# Why a multithreading C++ program crashes if we don't use join(), while a similar Java program doesn't

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, runnable

Let's say we have the following C++ program

```
void hello (){
   std :: cout << "HELLO"<<std::endl ;
}

int main(){

    std:: thread t(hello) ;
    t.join() ;

}
```

If we don't call join in this code, our program will crash because the main thread will terminate before the thread t1 is done. 
But if we have the same program in Java, the program executes normally even if the main doesn't wait for the thread.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Hello());
        t.start();

    }

}

class Hello implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

          System.out.println("Hello") ;

}
}
```

So why in Java the program doesn't crash? how the thread is executed even if the main finishes first ?

Comment: java is not c++, why did you expect them to be the same?

Comment: To be clear, the crash is because an unjoined thread will cause [`std::terminate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) to be called in [the `std::thread` destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's rather simple: In contrast to C++, which terminates once `main` has finished, a java program ends only if all (non-deamon) threads (including main) have finished (cf., for example, [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) oracle thread documentation):

> When a Java Virtual Machine starts up, there is usually a single
>   non-daemon thread (which typically calls the method named main of some
>   designated class). The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute
>   threads until either of the following occurs:
>
> a. The exit method of class Runtime has been called and the security
>   manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
>
> b. All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by
>   returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception
>   that propagates beyond the run method.

C++, in contrast, will start destructing objects with static storage duration, and if a detached thread is still running and accessing such objects, this yields undefined behaviour (cf., for example, [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.start.term#1) C++ standard draft concerning program termination):

> **3.6.3 Termination**
>
> Destructors ([class.dtor]) for initialized objects (that is, objects
>   whose lifetime ([basic.life]) has begun) with static storage duration
>   are called as a result of returning from main and as a result of
>   calling std::exit ([support.start.term]).

Answer (score 4):

The direct answer is following: your application crashes because `std::thread` calls `std::terminate` in it's destructor if the thread was not joined and is not detached. It is considered to be a nasty bug, to silently forget about non-detached thread.

You can avoid immediate crash if you detach the thread before returning from main. However, you are still likely to have all sorts of possible fireworks due to access to `std::cout` - which is a global object, and which will be destroyed after returning from `main`, potentially while your thread is still accessing it.

Comment: Side note:  C++ programmers _expect_ object destructors to close files, free memory, and generally clean stuff up. In some fantasy universe, we'd like the `std::thread` destructor to just kill the thread without making any fuss. But since in reality, there is no reasonable way to "just kill" a thread, it does the next best thing, which is to check that the caller either already has killed it, or has accepted responsibility for killing it in the future (by calling `t.detach()`.) Java programmers do not have the luxury of destructors. They have to clean stuff up more explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

This is because JVM has different rules for the process termination than C/C++. On JVM the process is terminated once there are no more non-daemon threads running. A C or C++ application is terminated once its `main` function returns. See [If you return from the main thread, does the process exit?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100827-00/?p=13023):

> the C runtime library automatically calls ExitProcess when you exit the main thread, regardless of whether there are any worker threads still active. This behavior for console programs is mandated by the C language, which says that (5.1.2.2.3) "a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main function as its argument." The C++ language has an equivalent requirement (3.6.1). Presumably, the C runtime folks carried this behavior to WinMain for consistency.

The C behaviour is like if you were calling `System.exit` in the end of your Java `main`.